# whats meant by 'path' in adsutil.vbs

Tags: asp.net, iis, automation, administration

I am trying to start and stop a website hosted in IIS with windows batch file and found that there is an option that with cscript.exe you can make use of adsutil.vbs file with START_SERVER option.

I know that the following command will do that, but I don't understand what I am supposed enter  for 'path'

```
cscript.exe adsutil.vbs START_SERVER     path     - starts the given web site
```

the documentation has a the following sample

```
cscript.exe adsutil.vbs START_SERVER W3SVC/1
```

but `W3SVC/1` no way related to virtual directory path or the application name.

can you please help me understand??

more info on: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/d3df4bc9-0954-459a-b5e6-7a8bc462960c.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IIS you have the capability of creating many web sites. Each site is identified by a unique siteID within the IIS metabase. Hence, `W3SVC/1` refers to the web site number one, which is usually the `Default Web Site` that comes preconfigured in IIS.

Answer (score 1):

Path is the internal key of the website.

[It is visible in IIS](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/39223/StackOverflow/Websites.PNG)